# How to connect to multiple databases in single application with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

We have a requirement of connecting to two Oracle databases and one DB2 database. We are using NHibernate 5 with Oracle Managed Data Access for Oracle. 
Although there are some resources available, most of them are quite old.

We have worked with individual databases with no issues, but never with multiple. I still have no idea how to start. Would really appreciate if someone could share some insights or some sample code.

Comment: I'm working on project, which work with MSSQL and FireBird databases. I simply create 2 different session factories which configured with 2 different `hibernate.cfg.xml` files (MSSQL.hibernate.cfg.xml and Firebird.hibernate.cfg.xml). This maybe not a best solution, but it works for me now:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating and maintaining separate `ISessionFactory` instance per database is the way to go. So in your case, you will have three instances. I have implemented this in one of my application where I connect to three databases with three different different RDBMS.

As you said, you have already worked with single database and NHibernate, I do not think any specific code is needed. Its same, just multiple session factory instances. Anyway, I have copied my code at the end of answer.

While creating `ISession` instance, make sure you are creating it from the session factory instance you want to connect to. Your rest of the application remains same.

Note that it may create an issue while logging like the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47921038/5779732) I faced. But, that was just one. Everything else went fine without issues.

## Sample Code:

**Note:** Some of the types in code below are NOT NHibernate types. Those are wrappers over them. Names are similar; so there should not be an issue understanding the code.

```
public sealed class NHSessionFactory
{
    /*
     * This must be instance class.
     * New instance should be created for each Database Schema.
     * Maintain the instance in calling application.
     * This is useful if multiple databases are used in one application.
    */
    NHSessionFactoryInternal nhSessionFactoryInternal = null;

    public void Start(NHSessionFactoryStartParams startParams)
    {
        Configuration nhConfiguration;
        nhConfiguration = new Configuration();

        nhConfiguration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, startParams.Dialect);
        nhConfiguration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, startParams.ConnectionString);
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(startParams.DefaultSchema) == false)
            nhConfiguration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.DefaultSchema, startParams.DefaultSchema);
        nhConfiguration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Isolation, "ReadCommitted");
        nhConfiguration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.BatchSize, NHSettings.DefaultBatchSize.ToString());
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(startParams.LogFilePath) == false)
        {
            nhConfiguration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ShowSql, "true");
            nhConfiguration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.FormatSql, "true");
        }
        else
        {
            nhConfiguration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ShowSql, "false");
            nhConfiguration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.FormatSql, "false");
        }
        nhConfiguration.AddMapping(startParams.HbmMappingInstance);

        try
        {
            nhSessionFactoryInternal = new NHSessionFactoryInternal();
            nhSessionFactoryInternal.CreateSessionFactory(nhConfiguration);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Stop();
            throw new NHWrapperException("Failed to create session factory.", exception);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if(nhSessionFactoryInternal == null)
            return;

        nhSessionFactoryInternal.CloseSessionFactory();
        nhSessionFactoryInternal = null;
    }

    public INHSession CreateSession(bool readOnly)
    {
        if(nhSessionFactoryInternal == null)
            throw new NHWrapperException("NHWrapper is not started.");

        return nhSessionFactoryInternal.CreateNHSession(readOnly);
    }
}
```

and below is the implementation of `NHSessionFactoryInternal` class which is used in above code. You may combine these two classes without issue. I have some other part in there; so I prefer to put it separate.

```
internal sealed class NHSessionFactoryInternal
{
    ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
    internal ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get { return sessionFactory; } }

    internal void CreateSessionFactory(Configuration nhConfiguration)
    {
        if(sessionFactory != null)
            throw new NHWrapperException("SessionFactory is already created.");

        try
        {
            sessionFactory = nhConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            throw new NHWrapperException("Failed to build session factory.", exception);
        }
    }

    internal INHSession CreateNHSession(bool readOnly = false)
    {
        if(sessionFactory == null)
            throw new NHWrapperException("Session factory is not build.");
        return new NHSession(sessionFactory.OpenSession(), NHSettings.DefaultFlushMode, readOnly);
    }

    internal void CloseSessionFactory()
    {
        if(sessionFactory == null)
            return;
        if(sessionFactory.IsClosed == false)
            sessionFactory.Close();
        sessionFactory.Dispose();
        sessionFactory = null;
    }
}
```